# css transition-delay on pointer-events not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want that links recover the ability of being clicked after there container has been hovered.

In the following example I apply delay on the visibility of links when parent div is hovered.

But I can't apply the same philosophy to the pointer-events attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/coolcatDev/trLf02e2/4/

html:

```
<div class="a">
    <a href="#">Some link</a><br>
    <a href="#">Some link</a><br>
    <a href="#">Some link</a><br>
    <a href="#">Some link</a><br>
    <a href="#">Some link</a>
</div>

<div class="b">
    <a href="https://google.com">Some link</a><br>
    <a href="https://google.com">Some link</a><br>
    <a href="https://google.com">Some link</a><br>
    <a href="https://google.com">Some link</a><br>
    <a href="https://google.com">Some link</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.a, .b{
    border:2px solid grey;
}

.a a{
    visibility:hidden;
}

.a:hover a{
    visibility:visible;
    transition-delay:1s;
}

.b a{
    pointer-events:none;
    cursor:default;
}

.b:hover a{
    pointer-events:auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:red;
    transition-delay:2s ;
}
```

Comment: any way of delaying the ability to click a link when hovering parent will work for me ...

Comment: Where are you specifying `transition-property`?

Comment: My understanding was that if not specified the transition will affect all changing properties within the hover

Comment: If you don't specify `transition-property` (either by itself or as part of the `transition` shorthand property), the browser has no idea what properties to transition on, and no transitions at all will occur.

Comment: It's not specified for the visibility nor color attribute but those are working fine in the provided example

Comment: In any case, `pointer-events` is not transitionable.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info

Answer (score 6):

I just found a great [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/IceCreamYou/q2zeb535/) to this.

```
@keyframes delay-pointer-events {
    0% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    50% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
.container:hover .element {
  animation: delay-pointer-events 2000ms linear;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 250ms;
  transition-delay: 250ms;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

The idea is as follows:

1. Create an animation that changes the desired binary property (e.g. visibility).
2. Attach the animation to your object.
3. Make sure to include the final value for the property in the style of the element, after the animation.

Answer (score 1):

```
a:hover {
  animation: disable-pointer-events 500ms;
}

@keyframes disable-pointer-events {
  0%, 99% {
    pointer-events: none;  
  }  
}
```

Comment: for posters scenario `.b:hover a {animation: disable-pointer-events 500ms;}`

Answer (score -1):

Try adding them to the selector and not the pseudo selector. (`a` instead of `a:hover`.)

[Example of transitions on W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: Same thing occurs. The hover state of the properties is immediately applied

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit)

Comment: Yes, that is not the issue, i guess transition can simply not be applied to those attributes, thats why the color change applies, the visibility but not the cursor nor the pointer-events properties