# Transition delay not working for pointer-events

Tags: html, css

In the code below, if you hover the right edge of the blue box, the red one will blink in and out until it painfully gets to the right side.

```css
body, html {margin: 0px}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  background-color: red;
  
  transition: opacity 0.25s,
              left 0.25s;
}

.blue:hover + .red {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  left: 100px;
  
  transition: opacity 0.25s,
              left 0.25s,
              pointer-events 0s linear 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue box"></div>
<div class="red box"></div>
```

But when I change `pointer-events: none` to something like `visibility: hidden` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371153/css-transition-delay-on-pointer-events-not-working) it works as intended, with the expectation of the instant appearance instead of a faded one. See the snippet below.

```css
body, html {margin: 0px}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  
  background-color: red;
  
  transition: opacity 0.25s,
              left 0.25s;
}

.blue:hover + .red {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  left: 100px;
  
  transition: opacity 0.25s,
              left 0.25s,
              visibility 0s linear 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue box"></div>
<div class="red box"></div>
```

Does `pointer-events` not support `transition-delay`? How can I achieve the effect without jittering and with smooth fading?

Comment: there's a problem with the way you use transitions. [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1) might help

Comment: @MahmoodKiaheyrati I don't see how I am using them wrong? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: sure. you should define `transition` in the element itself and then change the properties and not the transition to get affected on hover. and the `pointer-events` property defines whether or not an element reacts to pointer events. it has a 0/1 state that can't get transition effects.

Comment: @MahmoodKiaheyrati Yes, but you can still delay non-numeric properties as I did with `visibility: hidden`