# is it possible to make an html element non-clickable only for a period of time using css?

Tags: html, css, animation

i'm making a website for a school project and i want the links on the index page to be unclickable for only ~1.5 seconds. i have a fade-in that shows the elements of the home page, but you can click them before they fully fade in.

this is the code i'm using for the fade-in animation.

```
body {
    animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, css has no timers. You can easliy do so with JS though but I guess the answer for that you have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371153/css-transition-delay-on-pointer-events-not-working this should help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css transition-delay on pointer-events not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371153/css-transition-delay-on-pointer-events-not-working)